# Nginx redirection/rewrite: www to non-www and https

Tags: ssl, nginx, redirection, hostname

Note: See update below!

I have a Nginx setup regarding two domains, `example1.org` and `example2.org`, they're both handled at the same instance.

My problem is with `example2.org`, I want `http://www.example2.org` to redirect to `https://example2.org`, but when I type `http://www.example2.org` into the browser, I always end up with a "Privacy Error - Not secure" which lists the certificate of `example1.org`.

The problem seems to be that the `default server` part "wins" when resolving `http://www.example2.org`, which AFAIK, should not happen, and des not seem to happen

First in `default.conf` for `example1.org`, I have:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name _;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.org/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example1.org/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    return 302 http://$host$request_uri;
```

}

Then in `example2.org.conf` I have

```
server {
        server_name www.example2.org;
        return 301 https://example2.org$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name example2.org;
    root /opt/web-apps/example2.org/system/nginx-root; # Used for acme.sh SSL verification (https://acme.sh)

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/example2.org/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/example2.org/example2.org.key;
    include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2371;

    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

Any suggestions to what I am missing/doing wrong?

Cheers!

---

Update:

The browsers keep their own HSTS cache, which screws things up. Unfortunately there seems to be no way of disabling this serverside for a specific subdomain, like "www."...

Comment: You are missing a server block to handle `https://www.example2.org`.

Comment: Hm, I think maybe the question is a bit unclear, they're two different `.conf`-files, so basically they're the part of the same config.  I have updated the question.

Comment: My comment stands. You enter `http://www.example2.com` and the browser promotes it to `https://www.example2.com` because of HSTS rules. The latter URL is handled by default.conf as there is no other `server` block that matches.

Comment: @RichardSmith Ah, I see. -Care to elaborate , as I'd was trying to avoid certificates for `https://www.example2.org`, since I'm just using Cerbot, and have a about ten small sites that need to follwo the pattern...

Comment: ...HSTS is supposed to be an opt-in [https://www.nginx.com/blog/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-and-nginx/], so where is it opted in?

Comment: @RichardSmith Ok, ok, I'm too slow, I see what you mean now. +1. Give your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `http://www.example2.com` is not being processed by the `server` block you expect.

If you enable [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) for a domain, and include the "subdomains" clause, the browser will remember this for a very long time.

The browser automatically changes the `http` request to `https://www.example2.com`.

There is no server block that handles that domain name on port 443, so it is handled by the default server block, which uses the certificate for `example1.com`.